# Mockito: "Invalid use of argument matchers!", yet I am already using matchers consistently

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a test with 2 mocks. I prep the first mock with some `when` calls, then I prep the second mock with a `when` call that will return the first mock.

However, I'm getting an `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` on the line where I prep the second mock. Mockito does not seem to like the use of `any(HttpRequest.class)`. I've used this approach many times in other projects, without issue. What is the cause?

Some possible reasons for this error that I've considered include

- that this project uses Java 6. The `mockito-core` version is 1.8.5.
- that the `getResponse` method is defined only in the superclass of `SimpleHttpResponseProvider`.
- The `getResponse` is labeled `final` in the superclass. I'm not sure this would pose a problem for Mockito if it uses reflection. **EDIT: Yes, this was the problem.**
- that the `getResponse` method is `synchronized`. However, removing the `synchronized` keyword and trying again results in the same failure.

  ```
  public class Team5MockHttpServerTest {

      private HttpResponse httpResponse;
      private SimpleHttpResponseProvider simpleHttpResponseProvider;

      @Test
      public void whenAllBehaviorIsNominalThenExpectationsAreMet() throws IOException {

          int expectedStatusCode = 200;
          String contentType = "application/json";
          String body = "{\"message\":\"Hello world\"}";

          this.httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
          when(this.httpResponse.getHttpCode()).thenReturn(expectedStatusCode);
          when(this.httpResponse.getContentType()).thenReturn(contentType);
          when(this.httpResponse.getContent()).thenReturn(body.getBytes());

          this.simpleHttpResponseProvider = mock(SimpleHttpResponseProvider.class);
          when(this.simpleHttpResponseProvider.getResponse(any(HttpRequest.class))) // Exception here
              .thenReturn(this.httpResponse);
      }
  }
  ```

The error:

```
Running com.github.kristofa.test.http.Team5MockHttpServerTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.05 sec <<< FAILURE!
whenAllBehaviorIsNominalThenExpectationsAreMet(com.github.kristofa.test.http.Team5MockHttpServerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.048 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
    at com.github.kristofa.test.http.AbstractHttpResponseProvider.getResponse(AbstractHttpResponseProvider.java:77)
    at com.github.kristofa.test.http.Team5MockHttpServerTest.whenAllBehaviorIsNominalThenExpectationsAreMet(Team5MockHttpServerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
whenAllBehaviorIsNominalThenExpectationsAreMet(com.github.kristofa.test.http.Team5MockHttpServerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.049 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.kristofa.test.http.Team5MockHttpServerTest.tearDown(Team5MockHttpServerTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: Did you try removing the "HttpRequest.class" when(this.simpleHttpResponseProvider.getResponse(any()))
            .thenReturn(this.httpResponse);

Comment: Could you double-check which `any` matcher you are importing? Sometimes it happens that there are 2 conflicting libraries that provide `any` matchers. Make sure you use the one from Mockito

Comment: @yashsugandh : Yes, I've tried that. It fails to compile unless I cast `any()`, like `(HttpRequest) any()`. And if I do that, I get the same `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`.

Comment: @StefanZhelyazkov : The `any` that's imported is a static import from `org.mockito.Matchers.any`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with matchers. It was due to the fact that the method I was trying to mock was defined as `final` in the superclass. After removing the `final` keyword, the error disappeared.